# What's wrong in this snippet?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, stdarray

I have no idea what's wrong with this snippet. I'm getting this error:

> error: member function 'swap' not viable: 'this' argument has type 'const array', but function is not marked const

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct MyClass {
  std::array<float, 4> arr;  
  float carr[4];

  std::array<float, 4> getArrElement() {
    std::array<float, sizeof(carr) / sizeof(float)> out;
    return out;
  }

  void fun() {
    auto vec = { getArrElement(), getArrElement(), getArrElement() };
    std::reverse(vec.begin(), vec.end()); // <-- error line here
  }


};

int main()
{
    MyClass obj;
    obj.fun();
}
```

`getArrElement` isn't returning a `const` array. `auto` should be deduced to `std::initializer_list` but I also see no harm in that.

What's wrong?

Comment: The line above of your comment

Comment: I see, is there any way to have `auto` use a `std::vector` instead?

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know you want `std::vector` and not `std::list` or `std::array` or some other type? If you want a `std::vector` then write `std::vector`! (In a future version of C++ you will be able to write `std::vector<auto>` to deduce the element type, but you will still have to say what type of sequence you are trying to define).

Comment: `std::vector<auto>` is cool and that's what I meant. I guess I'm stuck with this then.

Comment: This `auto` fad is getting ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As above, plus if the array is only used locally and never truncated, extended or moved, then by using the free functions `begin()` and `end()` we can avoid the overhead of allocating a vector....

```
    using element_type = decltype(std::declval<MyClass>().getArrElement());
    element_type vec[] = { getArrElement(), getArrElement(), getArrElement() };
    std::reverse(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec));
```

Answer (score 6):

A `std::initializer_list` only has const iterators, so you can't alter its elements.

An `initializer_list` **is not a container** and must not be treated like one. It is a special <strike>hack</strike> language support type known to the compiler that exists to support a particular syntax. Do not try to use it as a general purpose container or sequence-like type.

You can do:

```
using elem_type = decltype(getArrElement());
std::vector<elem_type> vec = { getArrElement(), getArrElement(), getArrElement() };
std::reverse(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Comment: `declval` in my case since this was a toy snippet